# INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE с двумя ключами и ошибкой дублирования

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

Есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE `items`
(
    `group_id` VARCHAR(255)  NOT NULL,
    `id`       VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `name`     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`, `id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `unique_name` (`group_id`, `name`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
  COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
;
```

- В каждой группе свои уникальные идентификаторы.
- В рамках группы название записей уникальны.
- `id` не может меняться, `name` может меняться, но должно оставаться уникальным.

Запрос добавления новых записей с обновлением имен старых:

```
INSERT INTO `items` 
    (`group_id`, `id`, `name`) 
VALUES 
    ("group1", "id1", "name1"), 
    ("group1", "id2", "name2")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `name` = VALUES(`name`)
```

- Нужно обновить `name` для уже существующего `id`.
- Нужно получить ошибку, если будет попытка добавить новую запись с уже существующим `name`.

Выполняем запрос добавления новой записи, с новым `id` и уже существующим `name`:

```
INSERT INTO `items` 
    (`group_id`, `id`, `name`) 
VALUES 
    ("group1", "id3", "name2")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `name` = VALUES(`name`)
```

Запрос завершается без ошибки и без добавления записи, а нужно получить ошибку о том, что добавить не удалось.
Как можно это организовать?

Так как записи добавляются массово, то одиночные добавления или проверочные выборки - не эффективны.

Comment: Уберите ODKU - его присутствие в показанном варианте абсолютно бессмысленно. Уж лучше использовать INSERT IGNORE - тогда хотя бы можно потом получить уведомление о дублировании через SHOW WARNINGS - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3551afc2fdbe3fd00bdaa7f5ac83179b

Comment: Если совсем убрать ODKU, то перестанут обновляться name там где это нужно. Нет признака, по которому моно решить который из запросов должен быть с ним, а который без.
Например во втором запросе может быть так: ` ("group1", "id1", "name111"),   ("group1", "id3", "name2") ` и без ODKU ошибка будет по двум ключам

Comment: *Если совсем убрать ODKU, то перестанут обновляться name там где это нужно.* А где нужно? Покажите INSERT-запрос на показанных исходных данных, когда "нужно" и обновляется.

Comment: При уже существующих записях с id= id1, id2
`
INSERT INTO `items` 
    (`group_id`, `id`, `name`) 
VALUES 
    ("group1", "id1", "name111"), 
    ("group1", "id2", "name222")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `name` = VALUES(`name`)
`

Comment: суть в том, что запрос должен быть один, шаблонный. дубли id должны приводить к обновлению name, а unique key по name только контролировать уникальность. Здесь подошел бы некий механизм указания в ODKU по которому из ключей стоит делать update. Возможно есть что-то похожее, как в выборках можно отключать индексы?

Comment: А тогда не судьба. Используйте хранимую процедуру.